# Convert a dataGridView colum to checkbox column

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I am making a program to check how many courses I have left in my univercity.
I load info from a `csv` put it's data to a dataset and the display it with a datagrid.

I want some columns(lab and theory) to have checkbox cells so that I can check the courses I passed and then save them back to the `csv` to load them again later (when I pass somethnig :P).
But I have problem converting those (string) columns to checkboxes as I am not so experienced in c#

That's my code :

```
string delimiter = ";";
string tablename = "paTable";
filename = "aname";
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
dataset.Tables.Add(tablename);

dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("A/A");
dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Course");
dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Semester");
dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Theory");
dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Lab");
dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("Passed");

string alldata = sr.ReadLine();
while (sr.Peek() != -1)
{
alldata = sr.ReadLine();
string[] rows;
rows = alldata.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

foreach (string r in rows)
{
string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
dataset.Tables[tablename].Rows.Add(items);
}

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Side note, you'll want to be `using (var sr = new StreamReader) {  /* read fron stream */ }` or remember to call the `Dispose ()` method to properly let go of the `StreamReader` instance, see "IDisposable".

Comment: I use the sr.Close().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually created and added the columns to your `DataGridView`, I think you could keep your `DataSet`-loading process as is.

Turn off `AutoGenerateColumns` and add them manually:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name="Course", ... } );
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { Name="Passed", ... } );
...
```

The grid view should populate after you bind it with your `DataView` like you're doing:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

**EDIT**

Because it relies on strong types and proper binding, a perhaps better alternative would be to create a class to represent a CSV record (types assumed). If this class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface the values can be edited in the `DataGridView` and reflected in the class with minimal effort.

```
public class CsvDataRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _aa;
    private string _course;
    private int _semester;
    private double _theory;
    private double _lab;
    private bool _passed;

    public bool AA { get { return _aa; } set { if (value == _aa) return; _aa = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("AA"); } }
    public string Course { get { return _course; } set { if (value == _course) return; _course = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Course"); } }
    public int Semester { get { return _semester; } set { if (value == _semester) return; _semester = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Semester"); } }
    public double Theory { get { return _theory; } set { if (value == _theory) return; _theory = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Theory"); } }
    public double Lab { get { return _lab; } set { if (value == _lab) return; _lab = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Lab"); } }
    public bool Passed { get { return _passed; } set { if (value == _passed) return; _passed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Passed"); } }

    char _delimiter;

    // static factory method creates object from CSV row
    public static CsvDataRow Create(string row, char delimiter)
    {
        return new CsvDataRow(row, delimiter);
    }

    // private constructor initializes property values
    private CsvDataRow(string row, char delimiter)
    {
        _delimiter = delimiter;

        var values = row.Split(_delimiter);
        AA = (values[0].ToString().Equals("1"));
        Course = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
        Semester = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);
        Theory = Convert.ToDouble(values[3]);
        Lab = Convert.ToDouble(values[4]);
        Passed = (values[5].ToString().Equals("1"));
    }

    // a method to convert back into a CSV row
    public string ToCsvString()
    {
        var values = new string[] { (AA ? 1 : 0).ToString(), Course, Semester.ToString(), Theory.ToString(), Lab.ToString(), (Passed ? 1: 0).ToString() };
        return string.Join(_delimiter.ToString(), values);
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged interface requires this event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // helper method to raise PropertyChanged event
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The CSV file itself could be represented by a class:

```
public class CsvDataSource
{
    public char Delimiter { get; private set; }
    public CsvDataSource()
        : this(',')
    { }

    public string[] Columns { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<CsvDataRow> Rows { get; private set; }

    public CsvDataSource(char delimiter)
    {
        Delimiter = delimiter;
    }

    public void LoadCsv(string csvFileName)
    {
        string header;
        string data;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFileName))
        {
            header = reader.ReadLine(); // assumes 1st row is column headers
            data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Columns = header.Split(Delimiter);
        var rows = Regex.Split(data, Environment.NewLine);

        if (!rows.Select(row => row.Split(Delimiter)).All(row => row.Length == Columns.Length)) throw new FormatException("Inconsistent data format.");
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<CsvDataRow>(rows.Select(row => CsvDataRow.Create(row, Delimiter)));
    }
}
```

The DataGridView can then be bound to the `Rows` property of a `CsvDataSource` instance, so the form's code can look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CsvDataSource _data;
    private ObservableCollection<CsvDataRow> _rows;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void LoadCsv(CsvDataSource data)
    {
        _data = data;
        _rows = _data.Rows;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _rows;
    }

    public void SaveCsv(string path)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(_data.Delimiter.ToString(), _data.Columns));
            foreach (var row in _rows)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(row.ToCsvString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you'd have a button calling the `SaveCsv` method, and you'll want another button to add/remove rows to/from your DataGridView. Also you'll want to wrap file I/O operations in a try/cath block.

This is a quickly summed-up implementation that does require a bit of additional work to be fully functional, but it gives an idea, and works out of the box.

This way, the "defining the columns" part is completely taken care of in the `CsvDataRow` class which provides a strong type for each record. No `DataSet`, no `DataColumn`, no `DataGridViewColumn` either. Just the data, and some data binding.

Comment: This might be what i need but needs some work cause with the `AutoGenerateColumns` it displays empty cells

Comment: also with this way how can i check the contents of the csv to check or uncheck the boxes ?

Comment: @Tse just edited with an alternative, strongly typed solution. With this solution, checking/unchecking the boxes isn't a concern you need to care about: if it's checked in the grid, it's checked in your data source. If you changed the name of a course, it changes in your data source, automatically - thanks to `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Note that this alternative solution does use the vanilla DataGridView, with AutoGenerateColumns set to True.

Comment: Thank you ve.ry much. I am not home right now and i am using a netbook so i'll check it out as soon i'll return.

Comment: The part i didn't get is why i'll have to add/remove rows with a button. I don't want to do something like that. i want all the rows to be read from the csv only.

I have already a menu strip with Load/Save/Exit buttons so i have a warm place for the `SaveCsv` :)

I can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: I was assuming your use case here, maybe you wanted your software to allow editing the csv file via the grid:) ..an upvote makes a nice "thank you" ;)

Comment: I don't think i want to. I'll have the csv ready . But if i decide to make it editable i'll think about it. I'am new here so if i find how i give votes i'll certainly will. :) EDIT: Found it but not enought rep unfortunately :(

Comment: One more question. When i call the `LoadCsv` i give it the file path right ?

Comment: Yup. Path and file name :)

Comment: So for example i enter `LoadCsv("c:/file/something.csv");` ?

Comment: Might work. Or `LoadCsv(@"C:\File\Something.csv");`, where `@` makes the string "literal" so you don't have to worry about backslashes being interpreited as escape sequences by the compiler. I'd recommend not hard-coding the file/path this way though; make it a variable and pass the variable to the method.

Comment: Yes i am not going to hard code it but it gives me an error. What type of variable should i use string ? Cause it gives me an error that i can't convert string to CsvDataSource.

Comment: First create the `CsvDataSource` instance (passing in your delimiter) and call its `LoadCsv` method (passing in your string filename). Then pass the `CsvDataSource` instance to the form's `LoadCsv` method (perhaps rename the form's method to `LoadCsvDataSource`). When you display the form afterwards, you should see the csv content in your grid :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn:

So you need to replace the

```
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
```

with the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. Have a [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx).

Comment: It's `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, and `column` isn't being used in the posted code.

Comment: if msdn decides to load i'll check it out.

Comment: 'column' is used for some things that i didn't think are relevant to my problem

Comment: Typically you would instantiate a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` when you intend to add it to your `DataGridView`, as opposed to leaving the column definitions in the hands of your `DataSet`. Also if I remember correctly if the dataset defines a column as `bool` it will show up as a checkbox column.

Comment: Yes you are right about `bool` but with the process i use to load the csv content's to the dataset i can't make the "Lab" or "Theory" columns as `bool` .

Answer (score 0):

You can "convert" a textboxcolumn to a checkbox like this:

```
        dgv.Columns.RemoveAt(<NumberColumn2Remove>);

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn;
        chk.HeaderText = "<HeaderText>";
        chk.Name = "<WhatEver>";
        chk.DataPropertyName = "<DataField2Bind2>";

        dgv.Columns.Insert(<NumberColumn2Insert>, chk);
```